# Is visa's TPS very low at only 1700

Tags: transactions

I am analysing various blockchains to better understand advantages/disadvantages.
I recently cam across the comparison of Solana to Ethereum in terms of TPS; with Solana being able to process 500 TPS and Ethereum only 20/30 TPS.

To gain a better understanding of what is conisdered the market "normal", I wanted to compare to Visa, which according to [this](https://www.spglobal.com/_assets/documents/ratings/research/100495128.pdf) article processes 1700 TPS.

My question is, isn't 1700 TPS very low, that means that for every given second only 1700 can swipe their VISA card. Surely, there are more people doing that every second globally? Am I misunderstanding TPS?

Answer (score 3):

There is no global Visa transaction system. Each country/service provider/etc. settles internally, without communicating with the others. Whatever Visa "TPS" figure is quoted is not the figure of a global settlement system that Ethereum is. Thus, any comparison would be apples to oranges. Any Visa TPS number that does not cite public research and good evidence is probably misleading and incorrect.

For a comparison, each country or a payment provider could be its own Visa island similar to rollups are in Ethereum.